# Java 8 stream collect

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I do this in Java 8. I have an `ArrayList<String>` for example:

```
List<String> places = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Banana", "Coconut");
```

I want to store it in a single String as

- single item must enclosed in single quote
- comma delimited
- enclosed in brackets

Result: `['Apple', 'Banana', 'Coconut']`

Comment: And what have you tried? Have you read the javadoc of Stream and Collectors, to find which operations could help?

Comment: Take a look at [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
String string = places.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("', '", "['", "']"));
```

**UPDATE**

As another user made me notice, to deal with empty lists the code must be refactored:

```
String string = places
                 .stream()
                 .map(e -> "'" + e + "'")
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
```